# ElasticSearch 'range' query returns inappropriate results

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets take this query:

```
{
"timeout": 10000,
"from": 0,
"size": 21,
"sort": [
    {
        "view_avg": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "price": {
                        "from": 10,
                        "to": 20
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "category_ids": [
                        16405
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

This query on data set that I am running on, should return no results (as all prices are in 100s-1000s range). However, this query returns results, matching prices as:

```
"price": "1399.00"
"price": "1299.00"
"price": "1089.00"
```

And so on, and so forth.. Any ideas how I could modify the query, so it returns the correct results?

Comment: what is your mapping? is price a number or a string in it?

Comment: Can you show how you are running the query (i.e. curl, php, java, plugin, etc)?

Comment: Price is mapped as float. I am currently running it through some ElasticSearch frontend (not sure of the name of it, but it saus 'ElasticSearch' in upper left, sorry that I can't be more specific of the title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm 99% sure your mapping is wrong and `price` is declared as `string`. Elasticsearch is using different Lucene range queries based on the field type as you can see in their [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html). The `TermRangeQuery` for `string` type acts like your output, it uses [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (ie. 1100 is between 10 and 20).

To test it you can try the following mapping/search:

```
PUT tests/

PUT tests/test/_mapping
{
    "test": {
        "_source" : {"enabled" : false},
        "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
        "properties" : {
            "num" : {
                "type" : "float", // <-- HERE IT'S A FLOAT
                "store" : "no",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT tests/test/1
{
    "test" : {
        "num" : 100
    }
}

POST tests/test/_search
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "num": {
                        "from": 10,
                        "to": 20
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}

Result:

{
   "took": 12,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

If you delete the index and try to recreate it changing the `num` type to a string:

```
PUT tests/test/_mapping
{
    "test": {
        "_source" : {"enabled" : false},
        "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
        "properties" : {
            "num" : {
                "type" : "string", // <-- HERE IT'S A STRING
                "store" : "no",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see a different result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "tests",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually that was the case. while in config the price was mapped as float. But our elasticsearch lib, along the way overriden it to string (i was able to find this through __mapping). After we fixed that bug, and reran the full reindex, the issue was resolved, and now the query returns correct results.

Answer (score 1):

`price` needs to be a numeric field for that `must` to work. If it's `string` it will return. Make sure the mapping is correct, if it would have been `float` it would have worked.

You can check the mapping of the index with `GET /index_name/_mapping`.

If you would have had the following (and the `price` is `string`):

```
      "range": {
        "price": {
          "from": 30,
          "to": 40
        }
      }
```

that shouldn't return the docs because `1` (string) is before `3` or `4` (strings), even if numerically speaking 30 is smaller than 1399.